# CAS default theme property causing issue

Tags: jboss, themes, default, cas

I am deploying a CAS war file in JBoss 7.0 server. In cas.properties file i have given the property

cas.themeResolver.defaultThemeName=cas-theme-default

During WAR deployment, it fails with an error,

[org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Bean property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cas-org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties': Could not bind properties to CasConfigurationProperties (prefix=cas, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Bean property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Bean property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' of bean class [org.apereo.cas.configuration.CasConfigurationProperties]: Bean property 'themeResolver[defaultThemeName]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"}}

What is the issue. How to resolve this?

Comment: Is this due to some incompatibility between CAS version and JBOss version. I simply commented out the property and deployed and i got the same exception but this time for another property.

Comment: The same cas.properties file is working fine when deplyed in Tomcat. Only with JBoss deployment failure. Any Help?

Comment: share your configurations related to cas and your applications context file